# Q: What created my Google storage bucket images?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a single always-free tier google compute engine. That's all I think I have.

But I am being charged (slightly) for storage in a Bucket.

It shows up in this path:
`Buckets / [my project] / containers / images`

There are many files with names such as:
`sha256:05588f2fe61f8f1640b4391a250ba0f9c4bcea3bff7a3130ce92260a0590db13`
and are of sizes from bytes to hundreds of bytes. They have a date of Feb 6.

I don't think I did anything intentional to make these images.

How can I find out what has created them, and if they are used?

Answer (score 1):

These are container images and they're created by [Google Container Registry (GCR)](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/). GCR uses Google Cloud Storage (buckets) to store its images.

GCR is used by [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/), [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/) (possibly) and possibly other services that use containers (e.g. Kubernetes Engine) if you've used the project for a tutorial for one of these services.

As you point out, GCS is cheap. I recommend deleting the 'images' through the service that created them rather than by deleting the objects directly if you're looking to save the expense.

See the following link too for an explanation:

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/pricing#storage

**NB** The filenames are (SHA-256) hashes that uniquely identify the container images.

Comment: Hello @DazWilkin, thanks for your great information! I found the GCR entries (buckets) that relate to what I am seeing in my bucket storage. By the way, I downloaded a couple of the bucket items and they were gzipped tar files of what looks like parts of my compute engine hard drive.

Now you mentioned users of GCR, but as far as I can tell, I am not using any of those services. All I have is a single (free) instance of the Google Compute Engine.

Would you know how to find out specifically who is creating the GCR entries, and why?

Comment: The easiest way is to search the project's Activity Log, filter by Feb 6th and you should see what was happening in your project around then that resulted in the buckets' creation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question a few days ago, but that was when I updated a function in the firebase console, it went from having 800MB to 1.3GB, you can check this info here: [Pushing and pulling images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs%20/%20pushing-and-pulling) and also [Storage](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser)

I noticed that it creates a version of it and saves all versions of the same function in a container. And for now I just removed the old versions to avoid increasing the size of the Firebase Storage.

Greetings! :)